# Call PHP Class Function using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to post the form data into database using javascript. Here is my code.

### index.php

```
    <form action="" method="post"><input name="fname" placeholder="Name*" type="text" id="fname" required /><br/><input name="femail" placeholder="Email*" type="email" id="femail" required /><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Send Message" onclick="sendOutgoingValue();" /></form>
```

### javascript

```
 <script type=text/javascript>
function sendOutgoingValue(){  
name = document.getElementById("fname").value;  
email = document.getElementById("femail").value;  
myClass.extractIncomingParms(val, email, {  
});
}
</script>
```

### ContactData.php

```
<?php
$myclass=new ContactData();
class ContactData{
private $name;
private $email
public function extractIncomingParams($name,$email){
$fname = ($this->name, $name); 
$femail = ($this->email, $email); 
}
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the question/problem/issue?

Comment: Use jQuery or AJAX to send POST or GET request.

Comment: you might want to look up ajax because you cant call a php funciton using this myClass.extractIncomingParms, you can post to the page using ajax and process the return.  Sorry it just doesn't work that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not call your php class methode in java script

change your **index.php** to (This code use JQuery):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("#login").click(function(){
                var faname = $("#fname").val();
                var femail = $("#femail").val();
                $.post( "login.php", { faname: faname, femail: femail })
                    .done(function( data ) {
                        $("#res").html(data);
                    });
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    <input name="fname" placeholder="Name*" type="text" id="fname" required /><br/>
    <input name="femail" placeholder="Email*" type="email" id="femail" required /><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send Message" id="login" />
</form>

<div id="res"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

create **login.php** :

you can use your ContactData class in login.php and get your name and fname from $_POST

```
<?php

    include "ContactData.php";

    if(isset($_POST['fname'],$_POST['femail'])){

        $myclass = new ContactData();
        $myclass->extractIncomingParams($_POST['fname'],$_POST['femail']);

        echo "wellcome ".$_POST['fname']." ".$_POST['femail'];

    }else{
        echo "user name and password not set !";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that Javascript is running on the browser, while PHP is running on your server, so they cannot communicate directly. And this is a good thing!

You will need to create a PHP page to handle requests from the Javascript. Once that is ready, your Javascript will need to serialise the data on the form and post it to this page.

In short, your current solution is missing the layer that handles requests from the browser.

Take a look at this article, which is a nice walkthrough of the basics.
[Beginners Guide to Ajax Development with PHP](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php)